# Using C# to login to a website, not returning cookies back

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, httpwebrequest

I am trying to write some C# code that will log into the Battlelog for Battlefield 3 on the PC.  I have found an open source API written in php, but when i translate it to C# it's not quite working.  I used fiddler to make sure the headers match, both request look the same but the C# app won't return any cookies like the pc browser.  Also, is there anyway to tell when you post a form to a site the querystring id's that are being posted and the values?  I could not find that in fiddler, just the headers.  Here is my code:

```
 //LOGIN
        string formUrl = "https://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/gate/login/"; // NOTE: This is the URL the form POSTs to, not the URL of the form (you can find this in the "action" attribute of the HTML's form tag
        string formParams = string.Format("email={0}&password={1}&submit={2}&redirect={3}", "TEST@TEST.com", "PASS", "Sign in","|bf3|");
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        byte[] bytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formParams);

        //ADD THE HEADERS
        ((HttpWebRequest)req).UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2";
        ((HttpWebRequest)req).Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        ((HttpWebRequest)req).Referer = "http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/gate/";

        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
        req.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.8");
        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");



        using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        ((HttpWebRequest)req).CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        ((HttpWebRequest)req).CookieContainer.Add(resp.Cookies);
```

here is the open source php if it helps

```
            /**
             * Battlelog API
             * 
             * This API allows for the grabbing of Battlefield 3 player stats.
             * Note: It seems a valid EA login is still required to pull down
             * data...
             * 
             * For examples, updates and additional information, see the project page
             * at http://www.blakeharley.com/projects/battlelogapi/.
             * 
             * @author      Blake Harley <contact@blakeharley.com>
             * @version     1.3
             * @package     BattlelogApi
             * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2011, Blake Harley
             * @license     http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
             * @since       1.0-beta
             */

            require_once 'BF3Container.class.php';
            require_once 'BattlelogLang.inc.php';
            require_once 'BF3Soldier.class.php';
            require_once 'BF3Server.class.php';

            /**
             * This is where the cookies will be stored while connecting with the Battlelog
             * servers. Make sure PHP has read and write access to the file location.
             * 
             * @package BattlelogApi
             * @var string
             * @since 1.0-beta
             */
            define('BLA_COOKIE_FILE', 'cookies.txt');

            /**
             * You can change this is you want. Some user agents have been blocked, so it's
             * best to stick with impersonating a real browser.
             * For the curious, the current user agent is Mozilla Firefox 6.0.2 on Windows 7 64-bit.
             * 
             * @package BattlelogApi
             * @var string
             * @since 1.2-pre
             */
            define('BLA_USER_AGENT', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2');

            /**
             * You probably shouldn't touch this.
             * 
             * @package BattlelogApi
             * @var string
             * @since 1.0-beta
             */
            define('BLA_LOGIN_URL', 'https://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/gate/login/');


            /**
             * This class is the main accessor for the stats engine.
             * 
             * Example:
             * <code>
             * $battlelog = new BattlelogApi('player@email.com', 'p4ssword');
             * $jones = $battlelog->getBF3Player('123456789');
             * echo $jones->getScorePerMinute();
             * </code>
             * 
             * @author      Blake Harley <contact@blakeharley.com>
             * @package     BattlelogApi
             * @since       1.0-beta
             */
            class BattlelogApi
            {
                /**
                 * @access private
                 * @var string
                 * @since 1.0-beta
                 */
                private $_username = null;

                /**
                 * @access private
                 * @var string
                 * @since 1.0-beta
                 */
                private $_password = null;

                /**
                 * @access private
                 * @var bool
                 * @since 1.0-beta
                 */
                private $_hasCredentials = false;

                /**
                 * @access private
                 * @var BattlelogLang
                 * @since 1.3
                 */
                private $_lang = null;

                /**
                 * Stores the EA credentials so accounts can be scraped.
                 * 
                 * @access public
                 * @param string $username The EA account name
                 * @param string $password The EA account password
                 * @param string $lang The language to use for the translator (experimental)
                 * @since 1.0-beta
                 */
                public function __construct($username, $password, $lang = null)
                {
                    $this->_username = (string) $username;
                    $this->_password = (string) $password;

                    $this->_lang = new BattlelogLang($this, $lang);
                }

                /**
                 * Creates and returns a BF3Soldier using the given soldier's
                 * ID.
                 * 
                 * @access public
                 * @param string $soldierId The ID of the soldier
                 * @return BF3Solider The requested soldier
                 * @since 1.0-beta
                 */
                public function getBF3Soldier($soldierId)
                {
                    return new BF3Soldier($this, $soldierId, true);
                }

                /**
                 * Creates and returns a BF3Server using the given server's
                 * ID.
                 * 
                 * @access public
                 * @param string $serverId The ID of the server
                 * @return BF3Server The requested server
                 * @since 1.3
                 */
                public function getBF3Server($serverId)
                {
                    return new BF3Server($this, $serverId, true);
                }

                /**
                 * Uses the current session to get the text on the given url.
                 * 
                 * @access public
                 * @param string $url The url to grab data from
                 * @param bool $battlelog Whether or not this use is a subportion of 'http://battlelog.battlefield.com/' and needs the cookies
                 * @return string The contents of the given url
                 * @since 1.3
                 */
                public function getUrl($url, $battlelog = true)
                {
                    if (!$this->_hasCredentials)
                    {
                        $this->_getCredentials();
                        $this->_hasCredentials = true;
                    }

                    if ($battlelog === true)
                    {
                        $ch = curl_init("http://battlelog.battlefield.com/$url");
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, BLA_COOKIE_FILE);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $ch = curl_init($url);
                    }
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                            'Expect:',
                            'User-Agent: ' . BLA_USER_AGENT,
                            'Accept: */*',
                            'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5',
                            'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
                            'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
                            'X-AjaxNavigation: 1'
                    ));
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
                    $data = curl_exec($ch);
                    curl_close($ch);

                    return $data;
                }

                /**
                 * Gets credentials required the connect to the Battlelog servers. 
                 * 
                 * @access private
                 * @since 1.0-beta
                 */
                private function _getCredentials()
                {
                    $postchars = http_build_query(array(
                            'redirect' => '|bf3|',
                            'email' => $this->_username,
                            'password' => $this->_password,
                            'submit' => 'Sign+in'
                    ), '', '&');

                    $ch = curl_init(BLA_LOGIN_URL);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                            'Expect:',
                            'User-Agent: ' . BLA_USER_AGENT,
                            'Accept: */*',
                            'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5',
                            'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7'
                    ));
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, BLA_COOKIE_FILE);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postchars);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                    curl_exec($ch);
                    curl_close($ch);
                }

                /**
                 * Runs the given nameplate through the BF3 locale file to get the
                 * actual name of the item.
                 * 
                 * @access public
                 * @param string $string The nameplate to run through the translator
                 * @return mixed The translated id
                 * @since 1.3
                 */
                public function translate($string)
                {
                    return $this->_lang[$string];
                }
            }


            /**
             * Provides common utility methods for miscellaneous battlelog things.
             * 
             * @author      Blake Harley <contact@blakeharley.com>
             * @package     BattlelogApi
             * @since       1.0-beta
             */
            class BattlelogUtils
            {
                /**
                 * Returns the URL of a rank from the Battlelog CDN.
                 * 
                 * @param string $size The desired image size. Valid sizes are 'tiny', 'small', 'medium' and 'large'. Default size is small.
                 * @since 1.0-beta
                 */
                public static function getRankImage($rank, $size = 'small')
                {
                    $validSizes = array('tiny', 'small', 'medium', 'large');
                    $size = strtolower($size);

                    if (!in_array($size, $validSizes))
                    {
                        throw new BattlelogException("Invalid size '$size' specified");
                    }

                    return "http://battlelog-cdn.battlefield.com/public/profile/bf3/stats/ranks/$size/r$rank.png";
                }

                /**
                 * Returns the URL of a kit image from the Battlelog CDN.
                 * 
                 * @param string $kit The kit name. Valid kit names are 'assault', 'support', 'engineer', 'recon'.
                 * @param string $team The team designation. Valid teams are 'us' and 'ru'. Defaults to 'us'.
                 * @param string $size The image size. Valid image sizes are 'small', 'medium' and 'large'.
                 * @since 1.0-beta
                 */
                public static function getKitImage($kit, $team = 'us', $size = 'medium')
                {
                    $validKits = array('assault', 'recon', 'engineer', 'support');
                    $validTeams = array('us', 'ru');
                    $validSizes = array('small', 'medium', 'large');
                    $kit = strtolower($kit);
                    $team = strtolower($team);
                    $size = strtolower($size);

                    if (!in_array($kit, $validKits))
                    {
                        throw new BattlelogException("Invalid kit '$kit' specified");
                    }
                    if (!in_array($team, $validTeams))
                    {
                        throw new BattlelogException("Invalid team '$team' specified");
                    }
                    if (!in_array($size, $validSizes))
                    {
                        throw new BattlelogException("Invalid size '$size' specified");
                    }

                    return "http://battlelog-cdn.battlefield.com/public/profile/kits/{$size[0]}/bf3-$team-$kit.png";
                }

                /**
                 * Returns the URL of a ribbon image from the Battlelog CDN.
                 * 
                 * @param string|int $id The ribbon id.
                 * @param string $size The image size. Valid image sizes are 'small', 'medium' and 'large'.
                 * @since 1.0-beta
                 */
                public static function getRibbonImage($id, $size = 'medium')
                {
                    $validSizes = array('small', 'medium', 'large');
                    $size = strtolower($size);

                    if (!in_array($size, $validSizes))
                    {
                        throw new BattlelogException("Invalid size '$size' specified");
                    }

                    $id = str_pad($id, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
                    return "http://battlelog-cdn.battlefield.com/public/profile/bf3/stats/ribbons/{$size[0]}/r$id.png";
                }

                /**
                 * Returns the URL of a medal image from the Battlelog CDN.
                 * 
                 * @param string|int $id The medal id.
                 * @param string $size The image size. Valid image sizes are 'small', 'medium' and 'large'.
                 * @since 1.3
                 */
                public static function getMedalImage($id, $size = 'medium')
                {
                    $validSizes = array('small', 'medium', 'large');
                    $size = strtolower($size);

                    if (!in_array($size, $validSizes))
                    {
                        throw new BattlelogException("Invalid size '$size' specified");
                    }

                    $id = str_pad($id, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
                    return "http://battlelog-cdn.battlefield.com/public/profile/bf3/stats/medals/{$size[0]}/m$id.png";
                }

                /**
                 * Returns the URL of an item image from the Battlelog CDN.
                 * 
                 * @param string $name The item name
                 * @param string $size The image size. Valid sizes are 'tiny', 'small', 'medium' and 'large'. Default size is medium.
                 * @since 1.0-beta
                 */
                public static function getItemImage($name, $size = 'medium')
                {
                    $validSizes = array(
                            'tiny'      => '79x43',
                            'small'     => '90x54',
                            'medium'    => '147x88',
                            'large'     => '512x308'
                    );
                    $size = strtolower($size);

                    if (!array_key_exists($size, $validSizes))
                    {
                        throw new BattlelogException("Invalid size '$size' specified");
                    }

                    $name = strtolower($name);
                    return "http://battlelog-cdn.battlefield.com/public/profile/bf3/stats/items_{$validSizes[$size]}/$name.png";
                }
            }

            /**
             * Part of my efforts to produce proper error messages.
             * 
             * @author      Blake Harley <contact@blakeharley.com>
             * @package     BattlelogApi
             * @since       1.3
             */
            class BattlelogException extends Exception { }
```

I really appreciate any help! and thanks for your time!

Comment: You may need to URL Encode your formParams. 

Use Microsoft's URL encoder to make it quick:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx

Comment: If you could get your code somewhere public I wouldn't mind helping you out on this one.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to add the CookieContainer to the request before you call getResponse.

According to MSDN:
CookieContainer is a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) by default. You must assign a CookieContainer instance to the property to have cookies returned in the Cookies property of the HttpWebResponse returned by GetResponse.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx

In your example code you add the CookieContainer to the request AFTER it has already been sent to the server.

Comment: i just tried moving the cookie container declaration and still no change.  If io look at the resp.Cookies in the last line it shows a cookie count of 0.

Comment: Can you update your code to show what it currently looks like with this change?

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

1), Like @Bradley Uffner said you need to initialize a `CookieContainer` on the request itself ***before*** sending the request:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
//Init cookie container
req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
```

2), I don't know what happens upon successful login but upon a failed login no cookies are returned. I've verified this in code as well as through raw HTTP headers.

Below is a much simplified proof of concept against Google which for me returns 2 cookies:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/");
req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2";

HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(resp.Cookies.Count);
```